# Get text between 2 tags with Path in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I'm tryin to get the text between this .

```
<h1 class="hsf-article-title">Mini crab cakes with smarter tartar</h1>
```

So I tried this:

```
$name = $xp->query('//h1[@class="hsf-article-title"]');
$datas[$x]['name'] = $name;
```

But it doesn't work.

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query()` returns a `DOMNodeList`. You need to get the element from the list, and then get its text.

```
$datas[$x]['name'] = $name->item(0)->textContent;
```